# ESP32 Google Vision Face Detection request fail

Tags: esp32, detection, face-detection

I am trying to submit an image on the web to Google Vision Face detection.
Submitting the image directly on the Google Vision page:

```
https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/ocr?apix_params=%7B%22resource%22%3A%7B%22requests%22%3A%5B%7B%22features%22%3A%5B%7B%22type%22%3A%22FACE_DETECTION%22%7D%5D%2C%22image%22%3A%7B%22source%22%3A%7B%22imageUri%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.newdesignfile.com%2Fpostpic%2F2010%2F05%2Ffree-stock-photos-people_102217.jpg%22%7D%7D%2C%22imageContext%22%3A%7B%22languageHints%22%3A%5B%22pt%22%5D%7D%7D%5D%7D%7D
```

works OK.
Also using NodeRed on a raspberry Pi works ok.
But I can not make it work with ESP32.
It always responds on the console with:
HTTP Response code: -5
Error code: -5

My code is as below:

```
/*
  Rui Santos
  Complete project details at Complete project details at https://RandomNerdTutorials.com/esp32-http-get-post-arduino/

  Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining a copy
  of this software and associated documentation files.

  The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be included in all
  copies or substantial portions of the Software.
*/

#include <WiFi.h>
#include <HTTPClient.h>

const char* ssid = "mySSID";
const char* password = "myPass";

//Your Domain name with URL path or IP address with path
const char* serverName   = "https://vision.googleapis.com/v1/images:annotate?key=MyAPIKey";

String _request = "{\"requests\":[{\"image\":{\"source\":{\"imageUri\":\"http://www.newdesignfile.com/postpic/2010/05/free-stock-photos-people_102217.jpg\"}},\"features\":[{\"type\":\"FACE_DETECTION\",\"maxResults\":10}]}]}";


// the following variables are unsigned longs because the time, measured in
// milliseconds, will quickly become a bigger number than can be stored in an int.
unsigned long lastTime = 0;
unsigned long timerDelay = 15000;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);

  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
  Serial.println("Connecting");
  while(WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(500);
    Serial.print(".");
  }
  Serial.println("");
  Serial.print("Connected to WiFi network with IP Address: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
 
}

void loop() {
  //Send an HTTP POST request every 10 minutes
  if ((millis() - lastTime) > timerDelay) {
    //Check WiFi connection status
    if(WiFi.status()== WL_CONNECTED){
      WiFiClient client;
      HTTPClient http;
    
      // Your Domain name with URL path or IP address with path
      http.begin(client, serverName);
      Serial.print("Conected to Server: ");
      Serial.println(serverName);
      
      //If you need an HTTP request with a content type: application/json, use the following:
      http.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
      Serial.print("Posting request: ");    
      Serial.println(_request);
      int httpResponseCode = http.POST(_request); 
      
      Serial.print("HTTP Response code: ");
      Serial.println(httpResponseCode);

      String payload = "{}"; 

      if(httpResponseCode>0) {
        Serial.print("HTTP Response code: ");
        Serial.println(httpResponseCode);
        payload = http.getString();
        Serial.println(payload);        
      }else{
        Serial.print("Error code: ");
        Serial.println(httpResponseCode);
      }    
        
      // Free resources
      http.end();
    }else {
      Serial.println("WiFi Disconnected");
    }
    lastTime = millis();
  }
}
```

Assistance welcome.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to load an HTTPS URL over an HTTP connection.

You'll need to use `WiFiClientSecure` in order to use HTTPS - you can find examples in the [`HTTPClient` library](https://github.com/espressif/arduino-esp32/tree/master/libraries/HTTPClient).

Your code needs to look like:

```
      WiFiClientSecure client;
      HTTPClient http;

      client.setCACert(rootCACertificate);

      // Your Domain name with URL path or IP address with path
      http.begin(client, serverName);
```

You'll need to find and store a copy of the root certificate authority certificate for the domain you're accessing. If it ever changes (and it will eventually expire) you'll need to update that. Generally you'd define that at the start of your file - most people unnecessarily define it as a global variable, like so:

```
#include <WiFi.h>
#include <HTTPClient.h>

const char* rootCACertificate = \
"-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\n" \
...
"-----END CERTIFICATE-----\n";
```

You'd replace the `...` with the actual contents of the certificate. You can find many explanations of how to do this via a search engine or here on Stack Overflow. Make sure you write each line of it as a C string ending with `\n" \` so that the lines are concatenated into a single string.

You can sidestep the need for the root CA certificate by writing your code like this:

```
      WiFiClientSecure client;
      HTTPClient http;

      client.setInsecure();

      // Your Domain name with URL path or IP address with path
      http.begin(client, serverName);
```

this is fine for testing but it defeats the security that HTTPS gives you and should not be used in production or deployed code. Running it as insecure means you don't know that the server you connected to is the correct server and you don't know that the data you exchange with it (including any passwords or API keys) will actually be private from anyone trying to eavesdrop on network traffic.

Comment: Dear romkey, thanks a lot, you are right, I completely missed it and I am now using WiFiClientSecure client; as sugested but could not include client.setInsecure();, the compiler says ('class WiFiClient' has no member named 'setInsecure') but I have used WiFiClientSecure before and it works without this line. But it seems there is still another thing causing this problem as the original problem remains: response code and error code still returns -5.

Comment: If it says 'class WiFiClient' has no member named 'setInsecure' then you're still using WiFiClient and not WiFiClientSecure.

Comment: romkey, I am not that advanced and are pretty puzzled with what I am finding. I changed my code to WiFiClientSecure. I found at https://github.com/espressif/arduino-esp32 and there I found WifiClientSecure.h and indeed there is a setInsecure() statement. I searched my libraries directory and found no WiFiClientSecure.h and using the library manager I cannot find anything WiFi. I checked my preferences and https://dl.espressif.com/dl/package_esp32_index.json is there on board manager. Is there a orderly way to update my Arduino IDE so I do not mess things doing it manually? Thanks

Comment: Hi again. Problem solved. Your clue was 100% fundamental. I was still missing the line: WiFiClientSecure client; and was still using WiFiClient client and the compiler was not complaining. As soon as I figured out this mistake Google Vision started to respond with a proper json string. Thanks a lot for your time and guidance. Regards, Paulo

Comment: Glad you got it working. If you accept this answer as having solved the problem, you'll help other people who find this question know that it might solve their problems as well.